# How do you define an F# lambda function to return a specific data type?

Tags: f#, moq

I am trying to assign a callback using Moq and cannot figure out how to define a lambda function that returns a boolean value. In C# it's pretty simple for me to do but I'm having issues trying to translate this to it's F# equivalent.

```
let mockHttpMessageHandler = Mock<HttpMessageHandler>(MockBehavior.Strict)
mockHttpMessageHandler
    .Protected()
    .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
        "SendAsync",
        It.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>()
    )
    .ReturnsAsync(
        dummyHttpResponseMessage
    )
    .Callback<HttpClient>(fun r -> r.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains("SomeHeaderHere"))
    .Verifiable()
```

[image: F# Mismatch on expected expression type]

As you see from the screenshot I receive an FS0001 error stating the expression was expected to have a unit (void) type but it's returning a bool (which is actually the type I want returned.

The screenshot shows I'm looking for an Empty string which will not be what the final code reflects but serves as an example and a non empty string would still yield the same error anyway so kind of irrelevant of the issue.

How would I revise this lambda expression to express the function to expect the result of boolean instead of void?

Comment: The error message is correct. Moq's `Callback` function requires a lambda that returns `unit`, not `bool`. I think this is commonly used to [modify the data or cause some other side-effect](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#callbacks). Maybe you could post the C# code that you're trying to translate, so we can understand what you're trying to do?

Comment: I was going to post the C# code until after reviewing it again and observing your comment it appears it was error on my part in the translation. Even the C# code I referenced was illustrating manipulation of the data so it was not returning anything either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As brianberns said in a comment, the `Callback` function expects a function that returns unit.

You can achieve what I think you want with something like this (using Assert from XUnit here.):

```
.Callback<HttpClient>(fun r -> r.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains(") |> Assert.True ())
```

Comment: This was actually what I was attempting to achieve in my code and it works w/o the error now. I just have to address another unrelated issue of resolving the unmatched signatures of the method and callback. Probably need to create/derive some type of extension of the MessageHandler object. But your code recommendation solved the initial problem. Thanks